# jqgrid custom filter values should be set to existing toolbar

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have written a custom filtering feature by setting the custom rules to the jqgrid and the grid is loading perfectly fine.
I also have a toolbar filtering on jqgrid.
Toolbar filter and custom filter has some same columns. I am setting the values from custom filter to the jqgrid filter.
Now the call is happening twice and the grid is loading twice.
Question is : How to prevent the grid from loading after the value is set to the jqgrid column.

```
 <ul id="cr_taxYearList" style="display:none;width:70px;z-index:1000">                  
        <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/lookup/taxYears.jsp"></jsp:include>
        </ul>
```

taxYears.jsp code is:

```
          <s:iterator value="years" var="item">
<li><a href="#"><label><input type="checkbox" <s:if test="year == activeYear">checked</s:if> value="<s:property value="year"/>"/><s:property value="year"/></label></a></li>
```

</s:iterator>

JQgrid code:

```
  { name: 'taxYear',index:'taxYear',label: 'Year', width:50, align:'center', searchoptions:{sopt:['in'], 
              dataInit: taxJQGridUtils.buildMenuFilter(grid, 
                      {menu:$("#cr_taxYearList"), createMenu:true,checkBoxManagerOptions: {change:crTaxYearOnChange, fireChangeOnCreate:true},
                  widgetManagerOptions : {selectedText: "#", noneSelectedText:'None', buttonOptions:{icons:{secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" }}}})}}
```

Added a custom filter button to the grid using the functionality navButtonAdd.
To this added a bind event

```
      bindEvent : function(0){
         $("#filterBtn").on("click",function(){ 
     var yearfltr = $('#custRptTaxYear').val();
      //how to set the "yearfltr" value to jqgrid toolbar which is "cr_taxYearList" without reloading the grid.
         });
        }
```

For custom filtering I have written rule as below:

```
 var rule ='{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[';
  if(taxYearfltr != ""){rule += 
       '{"field":"taxYear","op":"in","data":"'+taxYearfltr+'"}';
            }
    rule+="]}";
    $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: {filters: rule}}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Now I want to set the taxYear dropdown to the value selected from custom filter div, without reloading the jqgrid.

Comment: Please post your code and explain step by step the problem in order to get help. This type of description does not help you.

Comment: Question udpated, please take a look and help me